# Got $2 in the mail from the Pew Research Center, is this a scam?

Tags: scams

Today my wife and I got a letter from the Pew Research center with a with a $2 bill enclosed. The survey has a link to the website: http://pewresearchstudy.com with a password, asking the youngest female in the household to take a survey. I'm a little speculative on the legitimacy of this survey and why they would give out free money in the mail.

Has anyone encountered these types of letters before? Is this a scam or a legitimate survey with real money being sent to us?

Comment: Just wondering—how could it possibly be a scam? They sent you cash in the mail. Where could the scam be?

Comment: I wonder what they want to know from all those infants that fit the selection criterion, and how they’d interpret whatever responses they get.

Comment: This is a rarity; an "is this a scam?" post on money.se.com that is not a scam!

Comment: A few years ago my wife got a $2 bill with a US Department of Labor survey.  That a Jefferson $2 is noteworthy is I think part of the charm.

Comment: @ApologizeandreinstateMonica: By logging in with the given password, you connect your physical address to your IP address (and possibly email address and other personal details if you give it out). It's maybe not a scam by itself, but can be related to nefarious activities. Asking for the "youngest" member with no age specification is shifty - it sounds like they're fishing for the most naive person to fill out a seemingly harmless survey. None of what I said is a fact (as per the accepted answer), but it's not unreasonable to naturally distrust this letter without fact checking.

Comment: While in High School I worked for a legitimate research firm as a phone surveyor. Twas a perilous time to be one. Telemarketers were at their peak because the Do-Not-Call list had not yet been instituted. Some of us would make hours of calls and not get a single survey taker because everyone believed we were trying to sell them something. The most desperate of companies would offer sizable sums for people to take their surveys. I think the same skepticism persists today and people are quite hesitant to answer surveyors. That $2s is how they are trying to communicate they want your opinion.

Comment: @EricLippert It's literally the first I've seen that asks "is this a scam?" but the best answer is "no".  Have you ever seen another?

Comment: @MontyHarder: Yes, 18 months ago: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/95847/is-this-200-welcome-money-from-a-major-bank-some-sort-of-scam#comment171570_95847

Comment: @MontyHarder: See https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/have-there-been-any-is-this-a-scam-questions-that-the-answer-was-no for a list.

Comment: @MontyHarder They aren't too uncommon, just earlier this month there was another one: [50k job is offering 90k worth of shares. Scam?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/116434/73731). They just feel that way because there are so many obvious scam questions asked.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It's probably legitimate.

https://www.pewresearch.org/methods/2019/02/27/growing-and-improving-pew-research-centers-american-trends-panel/

> a letter of introduction inviting recipients (and specifically, the adult in the household with the next upcoming birthday) to take the online survey, information about how to take the survey, $2 in cash as a pre-incentive and a promise of a $10 post-incentive for completing the survey.

Comment: FWIW my university did the same thing asking me to donate. I've also received 50 cents from Feed the Children or a similar charity.

Comment: For what it's worth Nielsen does this for their media surveys, too.

Comment: Is this now officially a new candidate for https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/have-there-been-any-is-this-a-scam-questions-that-the-answer-was-no?

Comment: Althoigh you might want to check ownership of that domain (for example, whether pewresearch.org and pewresearchstudy.com are owned by the same organization).

Comment: To confirm re: Nielsen, they do send the $5 after you complete the survey.

Comment: @ByronWall  I got the initial $1 to participate.  What to expect now?  Do they simply call?  What do they ask?

Comment: @JasonPSallinger, for Nielsen, it was mail only.  They mailed $1 along with ~10 survey questions.  I mailed it back and a month or so later a $5 bill was sent back. This matched their provided description of what would happen.

Answer (score 28):

They send money to guilt you in to responding.

Charities use this tactic too but usually with less incentive, a penny, nickle or quarter.  Pew must really want a response...

Comment: Especially with a $2 bill! I've only seen a few of those in person.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Every time I go to the bank, I ask for as many $2 bills as I can get. It's just ***so*** much fun to watch people's reactions when I use them...

Comment: The reason they really want a response is because they want the results of the survey to accurately describe the random sample, rather than to accurately describe people who are likely to respond to surveys. Non-responses aren't merely non-helpful, they're potentially harmful to the survey.

Comment: @MosheKatz I'm surprised they still print them.

Comment: @Mast they still print them, but not every year. They printed [over 153 million $2 bills in Fiscal Year 2019](https://www.federalreserve.gov/paymentsystems/2019_currency_print_orders.htm), and [57 million of those were in September](https://www.bep.gov/mprsepfy19.html). There will not be any printed in 2020 though, and the last printing before this year was in 2016 ([179 million bills](https://www.federalreserve.gov/paymentsystems/2016_currency_print_orders.htm)).

Comment: The set of people who will respond to the survey if given a "pre-incentive" is just as likely to be a skewed sample as the set of people who will respond without an incentive. It might be a larger sample, but it won't be any more random.

Comment: It's also a form of proof that they'll pay the $10 participation fee.  The cost of sending $2 to a bunch of people is expensive enough that they're probably also willing to spend $10 on the people who actually respond.  On the other hand, sending me a "get a free $10" mail without $2 means I'll just assume that it's a rabbit-hole of garbage, since people constantly promise me free stuff and only rarely deliver.  Also, sending money is an incredibly effective way to set your mailing apart, in terms of justifying the cursory effort of reading it.

Answer (score 3):

Your information is worth something to them. They're giving you part of that value in order to get the information. This is right, good, fair and not a scam.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Steve. Please consider improving your answer by adding some references, e.g. to a statement from Pew that they do this.

Comment: Rather, they're giving OP the money in the *hope* that they get the information in return. OP can keep the money either way. (I wonder how many people send the money back)

Comment: @smci You'd be surprised how much more compliant people are when they feel that it's their choice.

Comment: @TomášZato: please send me $10,000 so we can test that...

Comment: not only is it their choice, their assent has already been assumed. while they don't expect you to mail $2 back if you don't do the survey, giving you $2 in exchange for the survey *before* you actually do it makes a lot of people feel like the only fair thing to do is to do the survey.

Answer (score 1):

A complement to @Ron John answer.

It is legit As according to this third party article : [Did you get $2 in the mail from Pew Research Center? Heres the deal](https://www.wftv.com/consumer/clark-howard/did-you-get-2-in-the-mail-from-pew-research-center-heres-the-deal/813663266).

It is not an expensive practice,  indeed, the postage alone already cost $0.50 and the printout and cash enclose process cost more than $0.30. So the $2 is just a fraction of the survey cost.   Here is a research paper [talking about pre-paid cash as an attraction for survey responses](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/4967004_Prepaid_Monetary_Incentive_Effects_on_Mail_Survey_Response).

In addition, whether you like it or not, a non-reply will give another set of demography for the neighbourhood (thus the reply or no-reply is already a survey).

Nevertheless, an extremely high non-reply will also mean : i. The neighbourhood are free loader, ii. not many people stay in the neighbourhood iii. something wrong within the mailing process (It is instant cash by intercepting all such mail)